# Any way to automate a folder delete before building?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

Basically, I want to delete the folder named:

```
build-[Project Name]-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug
```

before compiling.

Comment: what toolset are you using ? MSVC, gnu make, eclipse, etc.

Comment: I am using QtCreator as my IDE. My compiler is MSVC2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to project settings (Ctrl+5, a.k.a. 5th mode), and add new build step with custom command 'rmdir', and arguments '/s /q path-to-target-directory'.

Don't forget that custom build step should be on top of list, before 'qmake' step.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at system command for qmake, which allows executing any shell command of the operating system:
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command

In windows you can put

```
system(rmdir /Q /S "build-[Project Name]-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug")
```

in your .pro file. If you need other platforms, you can check which platform it is and call appropriate shell command for that platform using same syntax.